# User owning multiple items in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database-design

So I have a few tables in a database setup and I'm wondering what the best way to do something is.

Essentially I have a 1-to-many relationship where a single user can "own" multiple items, which is represented by an array in php, which will likely return the unique item number, type, and values of the item.   How would I go about storing that in a MySql table?

Would it be best to have a lookup table of every single item along with it's ID and present owner?   Would it make more sense to put a line item in the user table that had a csv list of every item owned by every player (that would be a nightmare to index?)

What makes sense here?

Example:

class character contains items[]

character 1 has the following entries in his items list:

1, 2, 5, 10,11,12

character 2 has the following entries in his items list:

3,4,6,7,8,9,13

What would be a decent way to store this data?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never, ever store delimited string values in a database. Normalize your data by creating a  many-to-many table instead. That way you'll be able to normally query your data.

That being said your schema might look like

```sql
CREATE TABLE characters 
(
    char_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(32),
    ...
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE items
(
    item_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(6),
    ...
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE item_list
(
    char_id INT NOT NULL, 
    item_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (char_id, item_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (char_id) REFERENCES characters (char_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES items (item_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

If you later need to produce a delimited list of items per character so that you can then `explode` this values while you iterating over the resultset you can use a query like this

```
SELECT char_id, GROUP_CONCAT(item_id) items
  FROM item_list
-- WHERE ...
 GROUP BY char_id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51874/2)** demo